# Trying to get my program to continue with an if/else statement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm writing a program to fit this situation:
There are two children. They both add their money together to decide whether or not to spend their money on ice cream or candy. If they have over $20, spend all of it on ice cream($1.50). Otherwise, spend all of it on candy($.50). Display the amount of ice cream or candy they will buy.

```
I've written my code here:

#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void getFirstSec(double &, double &);
double calcTotal(double, double);

int main( )
{

//declare constants and variables
double firstAmount = 0.0;
double secondAmount = 0.0;
double totalAmount = 0.0;
const double iceCream = 1.5;
const double candy = 0.5;
double iceCreamCash;
double candyCash;
int iceCreamCount = 0;
int candyCount = 0;


//decides whether to buy ice cream or candy
getFirstSec(firstAmount, secondAmount);
totalAmount = calcTotal(firstAmount, secondAmount);

if (totalAmount > 20)
{
       iceCreamCash = totalAmount;
       while (iceCreamCash >= 0)
       {
              iceCreamCash = totalAmount - iceCream;
              iceCreamCount += 1;
       }
       cout << "Amount of ice cream purchased : " << iceCreamCount;
}
else
{
       candyCash = totalAmount;
       while (candyCash >= 0)
       {
              candyCash = totalAmount - candy;
              candyCount += 1;
       }
       cout << "Amount of candy purchased : " << candyCount;
}
}
// void function that asks for first and second amount
void getFirstSec(double & firstAmount, double & secondAmount) 

{
cout << "First amount of Cash: $";
cin >> firstAmount;
cout << "Second amount of Cash: $";
cin >> secondAmount;
return;
}
// calculates and returns the total amount
double calcTotal(double firstAmount , double secondAmount) 
{
    return firstAmount + secondAmount;
}
```

I input the first and second amount, but it does not continue to the if/else part. Can anyone enlighten me on what the problem is here? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
   while (iceCreamCash >= 0)
   {
          iceCreamCash = totalAmount - iceCream;
          iceCreamCount += 1;
   }
```

This loop will never end. Nothing in the loop makes `iceCreamCash` decrease in each iteration of the loop. Perhaps you meant:

```
   while (iceCreamCash >= 0)
   {
          iceCreamCash = totalAmount - iceCream * iceCreamCount;
          iceCreamCount += 1;
   }
```

Comment: ... and which can be computed without *loop* also.

Comment: Important lesson: never assume that not leaving a piece of code means you never started it. It was indeed getting to the "if/else" part.

Comment: or you could use `iceCreamCash -= iceCream;`.